# Funcionamento do "alert" no javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber o motivo pelo qual o código abaixo funciona quando o campo possui apenas algarismos (números), mas não funciona de existir pelo menos uma letra no seu conteúdo. Por exemplo, se o campo `NUM_ORDEM` (`varchar`) possuir uma letra, o `alert` não funciona, mas se forem todos algarismos o `alert` funciona, mesmo sendo um campo tipo `varchar`.

```
<script>
function menu_fim() {
    <?php
        $w = $total - 1;
        mysqli_data_seek($dados,$w);
        $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($dados);
        $x = $linha['ITEM'];
        $h = $linha['NUM_ORDEM'];
    ?>
    alert(<?php echo $x ?>);
    alert(<?php echo $w ?>);
    alert(<?php echo $h ?>);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Eu nao recomendaria fazeres desta forma, usa ajax em vez disso pra retornar a informação necessaria

Comment: Eu não recomendo usar dessa forma por estar bagunçado a estrutura (o ideal seria dividir as suas partes com algum _design pattern_, mas não acho que usar Ajax seja necessariamente melhor, pode ser que sim, depende do contexto desse código e do resto da aplicação

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo apoio. Eu realmente não havia percebido o erro. São softwares com muitos detalhes nas síntaxes.

Comment: Li sobre o Ajax. Vou iniciar o aprendizado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você tiver texto na sua variável `$h`, o código *gerado* pelo PHP será algo assim:

```
alert(Caracteres);
//    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
// Sintaxe Inválida
```

O que é inválido na sintaxe do JavaScript.

Você precisa tratar como se fosse uma string:

```
alert('<?php echo $h; ?>');
```

E para garantir que possíveis aspas não façam o código criar um erro, vale a pena usar a função [`addslashes`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php). Teremos, então:

```
alert('<?php echo addslashes($h); ?>');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, @David! Não se esqueça de clicar no ícone de check (✔️) para marcar a resposta como aceita, se desejar. :)